# how to select within groupby using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to select the row with a required value in a column using pyspark sql but it gives me error

Below is my table `session`

```
session_id  status    session_desc
----------  ------    -----------------
session1    Old       first_description
session1    Active    last_description
session1    Old       next_description
session1    Active    inter_description
session2    Old       next_description
session2    Old       inter_description
```

Below is my spark sql query

```
spark.sql("select session_id, (CASE WHEN status='Active' THEN session_desc END) AS session_description from session group by session_id").show()
```

But I am getting below error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'session.status' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

I need as below

```
session_id  session_description
----------  -------------------
session1    last_description      # can be inter_description as well (I don't care)
session2    null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your **`case statement inside subquery`** then **group by** on outer query.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----------+------+-----------------+
#|session_id|status|     session_Desc|
#+----------+------+-----------------+
#|  session1|   Old|first_description|
#|  session1|Active| last_description|
#|  session1|   Old| next_description|
#|  session1|Active|inter_description|
#|  session2|   Old| next_description|
#|  session2|   Old|inter_description|
#+----------+------+-----------------+

spark.sql("select session_id,last(session_desc)session_description from (\
select session_id,case when status='Active' THEN session_desc END as session_desc from tmp)t \
group by session_id").\
show()

#+----------+-------------------+
#|session_id|session_description|
#+----------+-------------------+
#|  session1|  inter_description|
#|  session2|               null|
#+----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: upvoted, adding a not relevant comment but future readers if looking for pyspark: `(df.withColumn("session_desc",F.when(F.col("status")=="Active",F.col("session_desc")))
 .groupby("session_id").agg(F.first(F.col("session_desc"),ignorenulls=True).alias("session_desc")).show())` :)